# Merge changes from one branch and ignore other dormant changes

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfvc, changeset

I have a scenario, where two developers are working parallel in a same branch of TFVC. Developer A and Developer B checked in from their respective branches and committed file changes. 
Is there any work around to push only dev A's changes on the server and keep dev B's changes dormant?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: with tfvc you can select whether you want to merge all changesets or selected changesets. select "merge selected changesets" and then merge them one by one. Might be a bit tedious but that should do it

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a branch(V1) from main branch, remove changes of the developer which shouldnot go to deployment from V1 and deploy V1.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc?view=azure-devops

I will suggest you to switch to Git as it more user friendly. Resources and help are easily and readily available for GIT
https://www.nebbiatech.com/2017/06/22/choosing-git-tfvc-vsts/